# Unity VFX how to get lifetime in script

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-effects

I need a way to get the lifetime of VFX in the script and I don't know what to do.
What classes should I use and what method should I use?

Comment: What VFX?  What script.  [ask]. [mcve]

Comment: What kind of vfx? Give us some more details please

Comment: I'm asking about the visual effect graph.